# css td:hover not working

Tags: html, css

```css
#navt td:hover {
  background: #000000:
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <table id="navt">
    <tr>
      <td>HOME</td>
      <td>SHOP</td>
      <td>SERVICES</td>
      <td>BLOG</td>
      <td>FAQ</td>
      <td>ABOUT</td>
      <td>CONTACT</td>
      <td>FB</td>
      <td>TW</td>
      <td>PIN</td>
      <td>INST</td>
      <td>ACCT</td>
      <td>CART</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

I've tried a few things and to no avail.

Comment: the issue is because of background: #000000:  . It should end with ; not :   and you can just use #000

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in your `css`.

```css
#navt td:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <table id="navt">
    <tr>
      <td>HOME</td>
      <td>SHOP</td>
      <td>SERVICES</td>
      <td>BLOG</td>
      <td>FAQ</td>
      <td>ABOUT</td>
      <td>CONTACT</td>
      <td>FB</td>
      <td>TW</td>
      <td>PIN</td>
      <td>INST</td>
      <td>ACCT</td>
      <td>CART</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written wrongly in your css code.
you are written `;` instead of `:` kindly replace this one. it will work

```
#navt td:hover {
  background: #000000;
}
```